# Where can I find a private Stack Overflow with a Knowledge Base feature?

Tags: wiki, knowledge-organization, stack-exchange

We had a sort of wiki for our company knowledge base (it was made with Google Pages). The issue we have is that a lot of informations becomes outdated very quickely.

We think our ideal knowledge base solution would be a mix of Stack Overflow and a tool like Confluence or Notion.

The **discussions would have a lifetime of about 1 or 2 weeks** and when the question is answered - it is integrated into **the knowledge base which has a lifetime of months/years**. If later messages happens on the discussion, we would know which articles to update if things have changed because the discussion shows the updated articles from this discussion.

Ideally, we'd like to be able to convert discussions to knowledge base articles and to quote articles in discussions.

It could be paid or free tools are not an issue. They just have to be priced for startups (not more than $15/user/month, monthly payment, no upfront fees).

I know the existance of Stack Overflow Business that seems to provide approaching features, but I have issues with it:

- The price and the upfront payment (it costs thousands of dollars the first day of usage, the trial is paid. We're a 10 people startup, not Microsoft)
- I don't know how it exactly works and if the Articles are smartly linked to the Discussions
- The articles editor. I plan to use the solution for sales and marketing people, I don't want to train them to markdown.

Answer (score 3):

You need https://www.question2answer.org/ . I am using that for my business website QA section.

It is free and open source.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a tool like Stack Overflow for your team, you might try... [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have found the solution you are looking for, but https://bip.so/ might just be the platform you are looking for.

It is a knowledge base platform created specifically for collaboration purposes.

If your team is either on Slack or discord, you can integrate your workspace or server to your knowledge base on bip. This not only allows for you to access these docs in knowledge base directly from the server, you can also **capture the messages directly from your conversations and add them to the knowledge base**. If I am not wrong, this is the feature you are looking for.

And bip has Moderated git-workflow, link embeds of youtube, twitter, figma etc. Also a bunch of social features, like commenting, emote reactions etc.

The pricing starts from 10$ month and that is not for a single user. In fact all the features I mentioned above are from its free version. You might want to check it out.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/64009)

Comment: Welcome Surya.  What affiliation, if any, do you have with your recommendation?  Our community has a strict policy that all affiliations must be disclosed within answers.  Please edit your answer to disclose any affiliation, if appropriate.  Thanks, and again, welcome.